# Sanitizing a String for a Property Name

Tags: c#, regex, string, sanitization

**Problem**

I need to sanitize a collection of Strings from user input to a valid property name.

**Context**

We have a DataGrid that works with runtime generated classes. These classes are generated based on some parameters. Parameter names are converted into Properties. Some of these parameter names are from user input. We implemented this and it all seemed to work great. Our logic to sanitizing strings was to only allow numbers and letters and convert the rest to an X.

```
const string regexPattern = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
return ("X" + Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, "X")); //prefix with X in case the name starts with a number
```

The property names were always correct and we stored the original string in a dictionary so we could still show a user friendly parameter name.

However, where the trouble starts is when a string only differs in illegal characters like this:

> Parameter Name
>
> Parameter_Name

These were both converted into:

> ParameterXName

A solution would be to just generate some safe, unrelated names like A, B C. etc. But I would prefer the name to still be recognizable in debug. Unless it's too complicated to implement this behavior of course.

I looked at other questions on StackOverflow, but they all seem to remove illegal characters, which has the same problem.

I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel. Is there some standard solution or trick for this?

Comment: you want something like if there exists three strings as "Parameter Name" "Parameter_Name" and "Parameter!Name" 
output should be ParameterAName ParameterBName ParameterCName

Comment: try this `[^a-zA-Z0-9 _]`. take note of the space , and the underscore. kindly comment if it works

Comment: You could store the value pair (parameter name, user input)

Comment: Is it ok to append at the end of the generated parameter name the number of occurrencies of that name? (at parameter name generation time) For example **Parameter Name** -> `ParameterXName0` **Parameter_Name** -> `ParameterXName1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can suggest to change algorithm of generating safe, unrelated and recognizable names.

In c# `_` is valid symbol for member names. Replace all invalid symbols (`chr`) not with `X` but with `"_"+(short)chr+"_"`.

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yu9Lab)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string [] props = {"Parameter Name", "Parameter_Name"};

        var validNames = props.Select(s=>Sanitize(s)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, validNames));
    }

    private static string Sanitize(string s)
    {
        return String.Join("", s.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(chr => Char.IsLetter(chr) || Char.IsDigit(chr)
                                               ? chr.ToString()      // valid symbol
                                               : "_"+(short)chr+"_") // numeric code for invalid symbol
                          );
    }
}
```

prints

```
Parameter_32_Name
Parameter_95_Name
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, works great! Also wasn't aware of DotNetFiddle. Very useful for these sorts of things.

Comment: @MartijnvandenH, fine! test it on property name with digits only (e.g "123", nov valid in c#) and decide how you want to handle them

Comment: Isn't `Char.IsLetter` more than just `[A-Za-z]`?

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev, `Char.IsLetter` is more than just `[A-Za-z]`. And c# also allows non-latin symbols for names